# Are $x^y$ and $x^z$ "Powers" of $x$?

Tags: terminology

Or would "powers of $x$" in those examples refer to $y$ and $z$, respectively?

Comment: The English term for $y$ or $z$ would be "exponent".

Comment: @Gae.S., that was the answer I suspected and, frankly, was hoping for.  I am relieved I will not have to fight terminology in order to succinctly state certain results in my writing.

Comment: I think "power" works too - reminds me of "power series", and makes me wonder why we don't say "exponent series"...

Comment: I think it's fairly colloquial and I'm not sure there is an official definition.  One will say "$x$ to the $k$ power" with implies that $k$ is "the power" but I have heard people say, and have said "$64$ is a power of $2$" so mean $64=2^k$ for some integer $k$.  Now that I think about it those concepts are irreconcilable but they are informal.  I *THINK* I stick with $x^y$ is "exponential expression"; $x$ is the base; $y$ is the exponent and if the exponent is an integer we can call it a "power".  I don't know though.  It's fairly contextually driven.

Comment: @WilliamBarnes Possibly a "power" implies an *integer* exponent.  After all there is nothing particularly interesting about $x^{\log_x w} = w$ and $x$ and $w$ are arbitrary (not $1$) positive reals.

Comment: @WilliamBarnes Huh? We're not summing the exponents!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression "$x^y$", $y$ is the "exponent"/"power" and $x$ is the "base".

But if $x$ is an arbitrary real number, I would not generally call $x^y$ "a power of $x$", though I might call it "$x$ raised to a power".

---

"Powers of $n$" where $n$ is a particular positive integer (or rarely, perhaps [a positive rational](https://footpathmath.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/powers-of-one-half/)) refers to the values $n^m$ where $m$ is an *integer*. In an integer-only context, the "powers of $n$" might require $m$ to be [nonnegative](https://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/computer/powers-of-2.htm) or even [positive](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/exponent-tables-and-patterns). But there are also contexts where we allow $m$ to be a negative integer (the famous film(s) [Powers of Ten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powers_of_Ten_(film)) is one example). Curiously, a phrase like "negative powers of $n$" is common, because context makes it clear that it must be the exponent $m$ which is negative.

It's difficult to provide a definitive source for the meaning of this phrase because it is not often carefully defined in textbooks. The [English Wikipedia page for "Power of two"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two) has some references, though.

Comment: Is Huey Lewis a power of love?